# Java Process Builder Whitespace in ExifTools Process for 360 Video

Tags: java, video, youtube, exiftool, 360-virtual-reality

I'm attempting to add EXIF data to videos using EXIFTools via a Java Process using something like

```
    //Projection Type equirectangular
    //Stitched True
    //Rotation 0

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "exiftool", "-Spherical=\"true\"","-Stitched=\"true\"", "-\\Projection Type\\=\"equirectangular\"", "-Rotation=\"0\"",
            video.getAbsolutePath()
    );
```

I can't get Projection Type to be added, because of the white space. The error is always something like

> "Projection is not recognised or Warning: Sorry, Projection is not writable"

This is what an EXIF report of a video that has it's exif done with the Google Spherical Metadata Injection tool looks like
[image]

This is what it looks like with my process[image]

The videos I'm uploading to Youtube with my exif data are not recongised as 360 videos.

So my question is, how do I get 'Projection Type' added via process builder (i.e. with the white space)?

Also, is this the only attribute I'm missing in order for Youtube and Facebook to recongise them as 360 videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Exiftool FAQ 2](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q2).

"When you run exiftool, by default it prints descriptions, not tag names, for the information it extracts.
…
To print the tag names instead instead of descriptions, use the -s option when extracting information."

To add the tag use `"-\\ProjectionType\\=\"equirectangular\""` or `-ProjectionType=equirectangular` from the command line.

I have no info on how to get YT and FB to recognize 360 vids.

Comment: Thanks yea that's helpful